# Does creating multiple meshes with the same geometry and material duplicate data in the graphics card?

Tags: three.js

If create two meshes with the same geometry and material.  Is the geometry and material duplicated on the graphics card or is it only in memory once?

Answer (score 3):

`three.js` can detect when shader programs and geometry data can be shared across render items. So there will be a single shader program and a single group of vertex buffer data for rendering both meshes.